# put selected attribute to option using alpinejs

Tags: alpine.js

I have a `select` tag and some `options` on it which has created by alpine's `template` tag and `x-for` attribute and its working perfectly but what I need is that to be able to apply `selected` attribute to the `option` based on the data I have in the page: for example:

```
<template x-for="city in cities" :key="province.id">
    <option
        :value="city .id"
        x-text="city .name"
        if(city .id == entity.city _id) {selected} // I mean this part! Is there any way to do such a thing ?
    ></option>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently You can use this syntax `:selected="someVariable == thisVariable"`

I am using **Laravel Blade** and the end code looks like this

```
<template x-for="province in provinces" :key="province.id">
    <option
        :value="province.id"
        x-text="province.name"
        @if (isset($entity))
            :selected="province.id == '{{ $entity->province_id }}'"
        @endif
    ></option>
</template>
```

Comment: You probably don't even need the `@if (isset` since the `selected` binding you're adding will only add the attribute if the id of the province is the one that's selected.

Comment: @Hugo, The `edit` and `create` forms are the same, in order to handle situations which there is **no** `$entity` variable and there will be an **error** on the page, the `@if `statement is necessary in this scenario **but generally** yeah there is no need for that `@if` statement

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, nice one